# Is there anything particular you have to do to make a constructor function?

Tags: vb.net

So to start this off; I'm a beginner in VisualBasic.Net and my classes require me to learn it. The current subject is object constructors and constructor methods. The current exercise (it's not graded or an exam) is requiring us to make a parent class with a constructor method, and a child class with a new() that calls said function. It looks a bit like this;

```
Protected MustInherit Class Vehicle()
   Protected ReadOnly Property Serial_No As Integer
   Protected Property Mileage As Integer
   Protected Property Color As String
   
   Protected Function CreateVehicle() As Object
   
   End Function
End Class

Public Class Car
   Inherits Vehicle
   Public ReadOnly Property Car_Type As String
   
   Public Sub New()

   End Sub

End Class
```

The thing I'm having issues with is that I'm not sure how to go about it? Can't ReadOnly properties ONLY be edited in the constructor itself, and doesn't the object need to be initialized in the constructor? Is there something particular I need to add in the CreateVehicle function?

I *did* ask the teacher but his answer was 'just give up on it and go do something else', which is ultimately pretty unhelpful.

Edit: (added the inheritance to the child class)
So, after being asked for clarification on what I'm trying to do; the exercise itself is not entirely about doing this, but it is the thing in the exercise that I'm struggling with. The goal is to create a Car object utilizing the constructor (New()), but the constructor must call a secondary function located inside the parent class, Vehicle.
My issue is the following : I'm not sure how to go about implementing the function inside the constructor. I know how to call methods/subs/functions and how to get returns from them, but I'm not sure on how I would go about returning a ReadOnly property's values from a secondary function. Don't readonly properties become uneditable outside of the constructor?

I could always return each value separately instead of as an object, and then set the Car object's values to be equal to the return of the function, individually. But then what's the point of calling a separate function instead of just passing everything as a parameter and doing it directly in the constructor?

Comment: `just give up on it and go do something else`  Not exactly expecting that Teacher Of The Year award.  Right now, your Vehicle and Car classes don't have any relationship.  It's not clear what you are trying to do here either.  Looks like Car should inherit from Vehicle.  If you created a Truck class, same thing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/inheritance-basics

Comment: Ah, yes! I didn't copy and paste the entire code because it was, all in all, some odd couple hundred lines and that is the one thing I was having issues with. I'll fix up the excerpt, thank you for pointing it out. The thing I'm having actual difficulties understanding as a logic thing (not as a syntax thing) is the implementation of the function. Is there something in particular I need to do in the function to successfully return the object's values to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what your teacher is looking for:

```
Public MustInherit Class Vehicle
    Protected ReadOnly Property Serial_No As Integer

    Protected Sub New(serialNumber As Integer)
        Me.Serial_No = serialNumber
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Car
    Inherits Vehicle

    Public ReadOnly Property Car_Type As String

    Public Sub New(serialNumber As Integer, carType As String)
        MyBase.New(serialNumber)
        Me.Car_Type = carType
    End Sub

End Class
```

Both constructors take in parameters so the ReadOnly properties can be set.